# Cloud Functions for Firebase - Merge multiple PDFs into one via Nodejs/Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to combine a bunch of PDFs via a Cloud Function and then have that merged PDF be downloaded to the user's computer.

I have a function in my provider that calls the cloud function and passes an array of URLs that point to the pdfs like so:

```
  mergePDFs(pdfs) {

    // Create array of URLs that point to PDFs in Firebase storage
    let pdfArr = [];
    for(let key in pdfs) {
      pdfArr.push(pdfs[key].url);
    }

    // Call Firebase Cloud function to merge the PDFs into one
    this.http.get('https://us-central1-rosebud-9b0ed.cloudfunctions.net/mergePDFs', {

     }).subscribe(result => {
       console.log('merge result?', result);
     });
  }
```

Has anyone had any success utilizing [pdf-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-merge) NPM module to accomplish this?

I have a basic cloud function stubbed like so:

```
exports.mergePDFs = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  cors(request, response, () => {
    console.log('request', request);
    response.status(200).send('test');
   })
});
```

Though when I try to call it, I get error code 500 just so I can see if it's being called.

Has anyone else gotten the pdf merging functionality working via nodejs/Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Comment: Out of curiosity: does the PDF merging work if you run it in a local node.js process? If it doesn't, you can eliminate Cloud Functions as the potential culprit.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? We are trying exactly the same but could not get it to work.

Comment: pdf-merge requires PDFtk to be installed on the OS. @FrankvanPuffelen, do you know if cloud functions has this installed?

Comment: The only binary I know of that is guaranteed is ImageMagick

Comment: I think this should now be doable with: https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib