# Merge PDFs collected from storage in firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, pdf, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to node.js and backend coding. I wrote an application (TMS) using vuejs. I need to create new pdf and merge 3 others (created on frontend and uploaded to firebase storage) inside of it. Here's my code:

```
exports.testCloudFunc = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async object => {
  const filePath = object.name;

  const { Logging } = require('@google-cloud/logging');
  console.log(`Logged: FILEPATH: ${filePath}`);
  const id = filePath.split('/');
  console.log(`Logged: ID: ${id[0]}/${id[1]}`);
  const bucket = object.bucket;
  console.log(`Logged: BUCKET: ${object.bucket}`);

  async function listFilesByPrefix() {
    const options = {
      prefix: id[0] + '/' + id[1]
    };
    in

    const endFiles = files.filter(el => {
      return (
        el.name === id[0] + '/' + id[1] + '/' + 'invoiceReport.pdf' ||
        el.name === id[0] + '/' + id[1] + '/' + 'POD.pdf' ||
        el.name === id[0] + '/' + id[1] + '/' + 'rateConfirmation.pdf'
      );
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < endFiles.length; i++) {
      console.log(endFiles[i].name);
    }
  }
  listFilesByPrefix().catch(console.error);
});
```

Can you give me an advice how to do this (what lib to use and some example code maybe)? Also I wonder what type of data is when I get files from storage and store it in array or variable. Do Can I avoid saving it to local temp folder for futher manipulations like merge? Or I can just merge it by giving a link to endfiles[index]? My project is 99% finished. This is the only thing left to do. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Anybody? Just provide me with a library name that should work in cloud function.

Comment: There is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128075/cloud-functions-for-firebase-merge-multiple-pdfs-into-one-via-nodejs-cloud-fun) where in a comment, a Community member mentioned [PDF-LIB library](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib)

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try